# Failing auth. via LDAPS

Tags: linux, active-directory, ldap, rundeck

I setup Rundeck with LDAP/AD auth via JAAS module (vide official documentation).

Auth. works perfectly fine with non-encrypted connection (providerUrl="ldap://AD-FQDN").

When I am trying to switch from LDAP to LDAPS (providerUrl="ldaps://AD-FQDN"), that's where problem begins.

I gathered AD cert along with Sub and Root CA's, added them into rundeck truststore (and keystore afterwards) and restarted rundeckd.

Certs are being validated successfully:

```
[root@rundeck01 ssl]# openssl verify -CAfile RootCA.cer -untrusted SubCA.cer ad01.cer
ad01.cer: OK
```

What I can see in service.log:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Firewall ports are opened (can connect to p. 389,636 from via telnet).

Running on:

```
rundeck-3.4.0.20210614-1
CentOS 7.9
```

Kindly advise.

Comment: Check which java you use to run the software. Java keeps its trust store separately from system and each java JDK will include its own. Personally, I would use a separate crafted trust store and use it explicitly by adding `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/my/keystore` to Java startup options.

Comment: Thanks Raspy. Now I have "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty"

Comment: Please check the path. Your keystore is probably empty or not accessible to the process.

Comment: For test i've changed keystore nad truststore perms to 0755 (and all dirs above), but still error is same. Ps. -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore= should point to keystore or truststore?

Comment: Trust store is a keystore that is used to verify other parties. Technically, from Java perspective, it's a JKS keystore. It should point to the file where you have included your trusted root certs. Default path would be `${JRE_HOME}/lib/security/cacerts`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Extract the ldaps server cert:

`echo -n | openssl s_client -connect your_ldap_server:636 > cert.out`

2. Import to the Rundeck's truststore:

`keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -file cert.out -alias myldap -keystore etc/rundeck/truststore`

3. Add the truststore path on your [rundeckd](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/system-properties.html#rpm-and-deb) file (`-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore`):

```
RDECK_JVM_OPTS="-Drundeck.jaaslogin=true \
       -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/rundeck/jaas-ldap.conf \
       -Dloginmodule.name=ldap \
       -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/rundeck/truststore"
```

[Same issue](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/6448) solved [here](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/6268#issuecomment-664425060).

Comment: But my AD cert is not self-signed. There is SubCA and RootCA involved. Should I put AD cert in keystore and CA's in truststore? Or should I merge all of them (cat ad.cert subca.cer rootca.cer > ldaps.pem) and put in truststore and keystore.